# PHP file doesn't show background image from CSS file

Tags: php, html, css

I have a problem - I am trying to include a background image using CSS for the  layer, but it doesn't work...
The CSS file looks like this

```
header {
background-image: url("boisko.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
background-position: center;
}
```

The main file looks like this

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
echo "<style>";
include "styl.css";
echo "</style>";
echo "<table cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" width=\"100%\">
<tr>
<td width=\"100%\" colspan=\"2\">";
include_once"Naglowek/index.php";
echo"<td>
</tr>
<td width=\"100%\" colspan=\"2\">";
include_once"Jezyk/index.php";
echo"</td>
</tr>
</table>";
?>
```

The background image should show in the cell where "Naglowek.index.php" is included, but it doesn't... That file looks like this:

```
<?php echo "<head><br><h1>Cracow Sunday Football League</h1><br><br></head>";?>
```

I know I could have written that file in html, but I would prefer it staying in php if it doesn't really matter.

Why doesn't my background image show up?

Comment: You should really rething what you are doing. There is no need to "echo out" html - just close the php tag and write html instead: <?php ... ?> here html <?php here php again ?>

Comment: please inspect html element .use browser console

Comment: When using images with CSS you need to use paths that are relative to the CSS file when not using absolute paths.

Comment: Are you getting PHP errors? Can you share those? Is the problem that the PHP file, Naglowek/index.php, isn't loading? Are you sure the file path is right? Why are you using `echo` over multiple lines? Each echo statement should be only one line long.

Comment: include "styl.css"; should probably be style.css but please rework that code

Answer (score 4):

You have `header` in the CSS, but `head` in the HTML

Answer (score 0):

Well you kind of have the right idea. You can save your file as a .php and still write the HTML that is needed.

Change the pages to look like this.

Main Page:

```
`<?php 
 <html>
  <head>
   <!-- title for the document, scripts, styles, meta information,and more -->
  </head>
  <body>
     <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
       <tr>
          <td width="100%" colspan="2">
            <?php include_once"Naglowek/index.php"?>
          <td>
      </tr>
          <td width="100%" colspan="2">
           <?php include_once"Jezyk/index.php"; ?>
          </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
   ?>`
```

As for the CSS I don't see anything class or ID called header so nothing is going to be applied.

```
<div class="header"></div>
```

As for the "Naglowek.index.php" file, it can stay the same as it being a .php file you just don't need the  tags. Just straight HTML will work.

```
`<head><br><h1>Cracow Sunday Football League</h1><br><br></head>`
```

You should get rid of the head tags because they are a container for all the head elements.

I hope this helps clear things up